# How can I work with micronaut 3 and google secret manager?

Tags: java, micronaut, google-secret-manager, micronautgcp

Currently migrating my application to Micronaut 3, I encountered one problem with [micronaut-gcp](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gcp/latest/guide/). Especially with the google secret manager. I am using gradle with Kotlin DSL.

Actual configuration: (not working, using plugin `io.micronaut.library` version `2.0.4`)

- gradle       7.2
- micronaut    3.0.1

Previous configuration: (working with no plugin, using `micronaut-bom`)

- gradle       6.5.1
- micronaut    2.4.0
- micronautGcp 3.5.0

**I/ The Problem**

My goal is to load some secrets as key/value pairs into a property source.
I followed the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gcp/latest/guide/#secretManager) that says to use a `bootstrap.yml` as follows:

```
micronaut:
    config-client:
        enabled: true
gcp:
    secret-manager:
      keys:
        - MY_SECRET
```

Then in my class I should be able to inject that secret value using the `@Value` annotation. Actually I am doing this in my tests. I am using the `@MicronautTest` annotation from jUnit5 so I have something that looks like this:

```
@MicronautTest
public class MyClass {
  @Value("${my.secret}")
  private String mySecret;
}
```

then comes the problem, when running any test, it fails in the initialization saying this:

```
Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.gcp.secretmanager.client.DefaultSecretManagerClient]

Message: getTransportChannel() called when needsExecutor() is true
Path Taken: new DistributedPropertySourceLocator(ConfigurationClient configurationClient,Duration readTimeout) --> new DistributedPropertySourceLocator([ConfigurationClient configurationClient],Duration readTimeout) --> new DefaultCompositeConfigurationClient([ConfigurationClient[] configurationClients]) --> new SecretManagerConfigurationClient([SecretManagerClient secretManagerClient],SecretManagerConfigurationProperties configurationProperties) --> new DefaultSecretManagerClient([SecretManagerServiceClient client],Environment environment,GoogleCloudConfiguration googleCloudConfiguration,ExecutorService executorService)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.gcp.secretmanager.client.DefaultSecretManagerClient]
```

**II/ What I've tried ?**

When I've seen that, I was thinking that maybe the `bootstrap.yaml` thing doesn't work the I tried to use the lower lever access to secret manager using injecting `SecretManagerServiceClient` as follows:

```
@MicronautTest
public class MyClass {
  @Inject
  private SecretManagerServiceClient client;

  private void someTest() {
    String mySecret = client.getSecret("MY_SECRET");
  }
}
```

but got same error `Message: getTransportChannel() called when needsExecutor() is true` with same path taken.

I also tried to upgrade to micronaut 3.0.1 but didn't change anything.

**III/ My solution to handle this**

As my problem was to retrieve a secret during the testing stage of my ci/cd process and, as I am using [Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build).  I could pass the secret using the [availableSecrets](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#configuring_builds_to_access_the_secret_from) feature in my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
 ...
  - name: 'gradle'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['./gradlew', 'test']
    secretEnv: ['MY_SECRET']
 ...

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/MY_SECRET/versions/latest
    env: 'MY_SECRET'
```

then passing it in my `application.yml`:

```
my:
  secret: ${MY_SECRET}
```

and then in my code:

```
@MicronautTest
public class MyClass {
  @Value("${my.secret}")
  private String mySecret;
}
```

But I dont find this solution very satisfying as I find the `bootstrap.yaml` one more convenient.

If someone gets a solution for me or an idea/advice, I'll be happy to take it.

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been down that rabbit hole. Long story short I got past this by upgrading the `google-cloud-secretmanager` dependency from 1.6.4 to e.g. 2.0.2

Like so:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```